# Creating a large number of collections or gathering in one collection

Tags: mysql, mongodb, collections

We have a table in MySQL called news and it has a field called user ID that specifies which news is for which user.
Now in Mongo, it is logical to create a separate collection for each user and not have all the news in one collection
For example, Collection 4 is for one person
In this way, all the news will not be collected in one place, but instead, the number of collections will increase
I just wanted to know if it makes sense without this? Is it the right solution at all?

Comment: In general, is it better to have a collection for 1 million users? Or 1 million collections for all users?
that the collection call time of each user is displayed separately

Comment: The way you store data in the database is guided by data models. Refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.